# Speakers not detected on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, sound, hdmi

I have my speakers plugged into my monitor and my monitor is plugged into my computer via a HDMI cable. I can play audio on my Windows 10 computer and I can also play audio on my Windows XP virtual machine. I can't play audio however on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS virtual machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could solve this? I have a Nvidia GPU and I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox for the virtualisation software. My virtualbox audio settings is using Windows DirectSound as the host audio driver and ICH AC97 as the audio controller. The host audio driver has another option called Null Audio Driver and the audio controller has an additional two options called Intel HD Audio and SoundBlaster 16. I'm not sure if changing them will do anything, but if so, which ones should I pick?

If there is anything you need to know about my system or virtual machine, I can try and supply that information.

Comment: Virtual machines typically don't detect the host's hardware but use what is presented t them by the virtualization software. Also not even the host is able to detect what is connected to a TV, the audio device is the HDMI connection. This is to say that your question is very confusing.

Comment: What's confusing about it? My speakers are plugged into my computer monitor, which has an audio line out port. My monitor is connected to my tower system via an HDMI cable. I'm more amazed at how Windows XP in a virtual machine can even detect this, when the latest version of Ubuntu in a virtual machine can't.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not following. I've been trying to solve this for a couple of days now but so far not having much luck.

Comment: The XP VM does NOT detect it. It detects what the virtualization software (BTW, which one?) presents to it. VMs use the host's audio device for audio, no matter which one. At the Ubuntu VM please check settings > Audio or Sound (mine isn't in English). Then [edit] the question and post what's listed there along with the virtualization software you're using.

Comment: I think that's what I was trying to say, but I just worded it wrong. I've updated the question.

Comment: I always use "Intel HD Audio" and for a Linux VM you may need to install Virtualbox's Guest additions for full hardware support.

Comment: Oh wow that actually fixed the issue. I can't believe it was something so small I was like trying things like installing nvidia drivers etc... I didn't think that the two operating systems would be different for the audio, despite them being completely different anyhow. Thank you for very much for the help! I can't seem to mark comments as an answer.

Comment: Posted as an answer now. And no, the Virtualbox VMs do not "see" the Nvidia Graphics and its audio over HDMI. Virtualbox shows only a virtualized graphics system. Installing Nvidia drivers wouldn't work in any case.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to realise that. I think what happened was I ended up following tutorials that didn't take into account of virtualisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an Ubuntu virtual machine in Virtualbox it works better with "Intel HD Audio" emulation.

No additional drivers are required.