# How to fix and enable HDMI audio?

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, external-soundcard

I have laptop HP Pavilion with geForce gp, and just instaled Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (had win10), one Monitor and pair of speakers. My problem is that I can't play audio on speakers. If I plug speakers into laptop, then it works but I want speakers cable to be plugged into Monitor (not in laptop). This is important. In sound preferences is only one output device but no HDMI. I tried PulseAudio also, didn't work. I tried couple of things but with no success. My problem is the similar with this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091164/speakers-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts) but i'm not using VM. While I was using windows, with same setup, it worked without a problem. I have not been able to find a solution to my problem although there are already similar issues. No solution works for me. I hope that I explained well what is my problem.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhYxl.png)

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia proprietary drivers installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. That may be the first thing I did.

Comment: If so I suggest editing the question to post a proper hardware specifications description along with the Nvidia drivers version (and how did you install it as a bonus; with 20.04 and before the installation of Nvidia drivers and others can and should be enabled during the Ubuntu installation). And if hybrid graphics please check which graphics is actually being used.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. I found a solution. Here is the link if anyone needs it. [link](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-option-for-audio-over-displayport-hdmi/175889)

Comment: Please expand your answer to include the steps you followed in brief. We consider a link to an answer to be "not an answer", so this will probably be removed